# How to Hide Part of the X-Axis (Time Axis) in Bar Chart Tableau CRM?

Tags: community, einstein-analytics, saql, dataflow, tableau-crm

I have a question about X-Axis in charts in Tableau CRM (Einstein Analytics).

I created a Time Combo chart with 3 calculations through a time line from 2019 to 2021. Amount the three calculations: the first one is set up in dataflow, the second and the third one are calculated in lens (not in dataflow), and they are calculated based on the value of first one.

Now I have a graph (see picture). However, even though my calculations must based on values through 2019 to 2021, I only want show values of 2020 and 2021. Therefore, in the graph I have now, I want to hide part of my X-Axis, not showing X-Axis in 2019, only showing it from 2020 to 2021.

I tried to add a filter for time to get 2020 and 2021, but because of the way I did my calculations, adding a filter of time makes my values wrong.

So is there another way I can do it?

Thank you all in advance!

[image]